# Angular and webpack 4.44.2 error Can't import the named export 'URL' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I working with Angualar 11 project using webpack. The project running on OpenShift. It uses webpack 4.44.2 version, node 12 version. The project suddenly on build phase throw an error

**[2021-09-21T14:59:36.679Z] Can't import the named export 'URL' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)**

My webpack config file is:

```
const path = require("path");

const { NODE_ENV = "production" } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  entry: "./server",
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: "node",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "server.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  },
};
```

in my package.json file the  build command is :

```
"build:server": "webpack --config=./webpack-server.config.js"
```

Comment: did you find a solution?